# Matplotlib cumulative plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

What matplotlib function I should use for creating such "above" plots?

I've tried to find it in [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), but I've not managed to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a solution on this : http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stackplot_demo.html

Comment: Try to avoid link-only answers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner on this forum. I'll try to do better next time.

Comment: Hi @jumpy, this is probably exactly what the OP wants, if you add a minimal example using the `stackplot_demo` you've linked it'll be a good answer

Answer (score 5):

You could use `matplotlib` `fill_between`, for example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.1)
y = 10*np.ones(x.shape[0])
c = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'y', 'k']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(5):
    r = np.random.randn(x.shape[0])
    yp = np.copy(y)
    y = y + np.cumsum(np.abs(r))
    ax.fill_between(x, yp, y, color=c[i], alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Would look like,
[image]